# dnsmasq - Redirect URL request to guest VM

Tags: macos, dns, apache-http-server, dnsmasq

I am running Linux Apache on my local Parallels VM as a guest, my goal is: redirect an URL request (http://test.dev) from host (OS X) to Linux Guest. I had a local dnsmasq setup with MAMP (which worked fine) but there are some limitations in MAMP that are really bothering me.

Local Linux Apache is reachable from a guest IP.

Is it possible to set things up?

I have already set up dnsmasq.conf:

```
address=/.dev/10.169.55.1
```

Even /etc/resover/dev:

```
nameserver 10.169.55.1
port 80
domain .
```

But it's not working properly (command "host test.dev" does not return a DNS server for given address)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `address=/dev/10.169.55.1` in dnsmasq, with not starting dot.

Don't forget to clean local OSX DNS cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache`